# LibGDX: ImageButton clicklistener not working

Tags: libgdx, onclick, onclicklistener, imagebutton

This is my code:

```
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
        bagImage = new Image(new Texture("bag.png"));
        bagButton = new ImageButton(bagImage.getDrawable());
        bagButton.setSize(125, 125);
        bagButton.addListener(new ClickListener() {
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                Gdx.app.debug("DEBUG", "clicked");
            }
        });
    }
```

If I click on the button nothing happens. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have `stage` and add `ImageButton` to this stage then `setInputProcessor` to this stage and you can use only Image instead of ImageButton since you don't use imageUp, imageDown.....

you code should be like this :

```
Stage stage = new Stage();
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage); 
bagImage = new Image(new Texture("bag.png"));
bagImage.setSize(125, 125);
stage.addActor(bagImage);
bagImage.addListener(new ClickListener() { 
    public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y){
        Gdx.app.debug("DEBUG", "clicked");
        }
    });

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    stage.act(delta);
    stage.draw();
}
```